# wxWidgets Dialog Layouting with the Gridbagsizer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, wxwidgets

I'm basically trying to make a simple dialog. The problem with it is, that no matter  what i do with the help of the wxGridbagsizer, the buttons always appear on the left corner (over each other).

Code snippet:

```
wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this,-1);

wxButton* b1 = new wxButton(panel,wxID_ANY,L"OK",wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize,0);
wxButton* b2 = new wxButton(panel,wxID_ANY,L"Cancel",wxDefaultPosition,wxDefaultSize,0);
gbs->Add(b1,wxGBPosition(1,1));
gbs->Add(b2,wxGBPosition(2,2));


gbs->Fit(panel);
```

Comment: When i worked in WxWidgets I always used WxWidget IDE, have you tried to use it and see the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sizer layout is not being executed.  It is hard to be sure what is wrong, because your code snippet leaves out so much - for example I assume you are calling the sizer's constructor but you do not show the code.  Anyway,  I expect the problem is that you have not told the panel about your sizer.

```
panel->SetSizer( gbs );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use DialogBlocks and see what code it generates to understand the workflow of usage of grid bag sizer.

```
void Yarrr1::CreateControls()
{    
////@begin Yarrr1 content construction
    Yarrr1* itemPanel1 = this;

    wxGridBagSizer* itemGridBagSizer2 = new wxGridBagSizer(0, 0);
    itemGridBagSizer2->SetEmptyCellSize(wxSize(10, 20));
    itemPanel1->SetSizer(itemGridBagSizer2);

    wxButton* itemButton3 = new wxButton( itemPanel1, ID_BUTTON6, _("Button"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    itemGridBagSizer2->Add(itemButton3, wxGBPosition(0, 0), wxGBSpan(1, 1), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL, 5);

    wxButton* itemButton4 = new wxButton( itemPanel1, ID_BUTTON7, _("Button"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    itemGridBagSizer2->Add(itemButton4, wxGBPosition(1, 1), wxGBSpan(1, 1), wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL, 5);

////@end Yarrr1 content construction
}
```

Produces http://screencast.com/t/mANmpGmGb20